# Unexpected Token, expected { (26:2)

Tags: react-native

I'm new in ths and I can't figure out what's is wrong in this line code.
I try to change the line and the error only change the subject.

```html
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { Textbox } from './src/Textbox';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hello Hector. Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export class Textbox extends Component ({
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.useless}> 
        <Textbox />
      </View>
    );
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error on your 2nd class:

```
export class Textbox extends Component ({ <---shouldnt have parans
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.useless}> 
        <Textbox />
      </View>
    );
  },
});   <---shouldnt have parans
```

Change it to:

```
 export class Textbox extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.useless}> 
        <Textbox />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```